# Why same fonts are showing different look on different roku devices?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I am working on bright script using scene graph. I have used fonts(Lato-Light, Lato-Regular and Lato-Bold) but these font shows different look (UI) in multiple roku devices. I have tested it in different roku devices(Roku-2, Roku-3, Roku-4 and Rock-stick). Font should be display same in all devices
Please provide suggestion to resolve it.

[image: Roku Stick screenshot]

[image: Roku-3 screenshot]

[image: Roku-4 screenshot]

Comment: Can you post some screenshots demonstrating the problem?

Comment: I have attached screenshot the same page of all devices. 
It appear differences that Roku 4 font is a heavier weight than the Roku 3.

Comment: trackback https://forums.roku.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=97313